# SQL: SybaseDB and having parameterized variables in SELECT clauses

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I am trying to create a stored procedure that selects from a database name that would be parameterized. However, I am having a lot of trouble doing so. I am trying to perform something as simple as the following:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR
SET @tableName = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'

SELECT
  *
FROM
  @tableName
```

This produces the error: `Incorrect syntax near '@tableName'.`

Could someone please tell me how I could select from a parameterized table name?

Comment: You cannot parameterize table names.  You need to use dynamic SQL for this purpose -- create the SQL as a string and then execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute dynamic SQL in this case.

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR 
SET @tableName = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
exec('
SELECT
  *
FROM ' + @tableName )
```